# Why do maven version have SNAPSHOT in them?

Tags: java, maven

What is the convention in having a SNAPSHOT in maven version names?
What does SNAPSHOT mean and when should I use it in the version name of my project?

Example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-project</artifactId>
  <version>9.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From maven [doc](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/).

**version** This element indicates the version of the artifact generated by the project. Maven goes a long way to help you with version management and you will often see the SNAPSHOT designator in a version, which indicates that a project is in a state of development. We will discuss the use of snapshots and how they work further on in this guide.

So if your project consists of multiple modules and module could be changed and you need always a fresh version include the snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

a SNAPSHOT is an upload of the most recent version:

**http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_(computer_storage)**

You could use older stable versions if you do not wish to have the latest version.